# Detecting checkbox change with a listview Java Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm new to both Java and Android development and am wondering how I would go about using a listener to detect when a check box is checked/unchecked. I understand how to do this if the check box was by itself however how would I do it if the checkbox is inside of a list view?

Hopefully this is not too vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using a custom xml for the listview item. In that case, you have to also create a custom Adapter for the listview, and add the listener to the checkboxes there.